# Отображение сотых, даже если 00

Tags: php

Как вывести число с сотыми, если число уже к примеру: 52, чтобы вывести 52.00?

```
echo round(52.00, 2);// Выводит 52
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format(52.00, 2);// Выводит 52.00
```